# Python: reduce on tuple of tuples

Tags: python, lambda, reduce, euclidean-distance

I am trying to compute in Python the length of the path from a point A to a point B going through a list of intermediary points. **I know how to do it but I do want to use the reduce Built-in function**.

Why I tried so far, **please note that it is completely wrong**, is this:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: math.sqrt((y[1]-y[0])**2+(x[1]-x[0])**2) , ((1,2),(3,4),(1,8)))
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do this using `reduce` or at least it is not the optimal way imo. Theoretically, `reduce` will give you the computed distance so far and one point as parameters, but you'd two points to compute the distance. Maybe there is a fancy way to do it, but why not just iterate over the list?

Comment: Simple speedup trick is to operate on squares, an do sqrt at the end.

Comment: @qba: where did you get the idea that the sqrt of a sum is equal to the sum of sqrts? e.g.: `sqrt(2)+sqrt(2)!=sqrt(2+2)`

Comment: thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should map before you reduce.

```
points = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 8)]
distances = (math.hypot(b[0]-a[0], b[1]-a[1])
             for a, b in zip(points, points[1:]))
total_distance = sum(distances)
```

or, if you *must* use `reduce()`, although `sum()` is better for this purpose:

```
import operator

total_distance = reduce(operator.add, distances)
```

If you have a lot of points, you might find NumPy helpful in doing this all at once, quickly:

```
import numpy

total_distance = numpy.hypot(*numpy.diff(numpy.array(points), axis=0)).sum()
```

**Edit**: use `math.hypot()` and add NumPy method.

Comment: there is function hypot in math

Comment: This solution buffers the input so it will be expensive for longer sequences unless the `zip` expression is refactored a little.

Comment: If you need something efficient, then the NumPy solution is probably best. If you must only use the standard library, then @Raymond Hettinger's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170562/python-reduce-on-tuple-of-tuples/8170716#8170716) below shows how to do this with `itertools.tee()` and `itertools.izip()`.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't pretty but it can be done :-)

```
>>> tot = ((1,2),(3,4),(1,8))
>>> reduce(lambda d,((x0,y0),(x1,y1)): d + ((x1-x0)**2+(y1-y0)**2)**0.5, zip(tot[1:], tot[0:]), 0.0)
7.3005630797457695
```

Comment: To avoid buffering for longer sequences the `zip` expression would need some refactoring.  But kudos for the clever hack.  +1

Comment: You can always substitute *itertools.izip* if sequence length is of concern.  Thanks for the upvote :-)

Comment: I was referring to the shift implemented with slices, which even with `izip` uses twice the memory cost of the original sequence.

Comment: Use itertools.tee() for the split and next() to consume the first value from one of them (there is an example for this in the itertools recipes):   ``t1,t2=tee(tot); next(t2, None); it=izip(t1, t2); reduce(lambda d,((x0,y0),(x1,y1)): d + ((x1-x0)**2+(y1-y0)**2)**0.5, it, 0)``

Answer (score 2):

`reduce()` is simply the wrong tool for this purpose.  It *is* possible to do it with `reduce()`, but it is a bit weird:

```
def distance((x, d), y):
    return y, d + math.hypot(y[0] - x[0], y[1] - x[1])

print reduce(distance, [(3,4),(1,8)], ((1, 2), 0.0))[1]
```

prints

```
7.30056307975
```

The last parameter passed to the `reduce()` call is the starting point and the initial value for the distance.

Comment: +1 from me.  Your answer is exactly what the OP asked for.  Maybe people are downvoting *reduce* itself and not your answer.

Answer (score 1):

reduce does not work that way, you start with an initial value a, which you specify or is taken as first element from your iterable. afterwards, you pass a,next_element to the function (lambda) provided and store the result in a, repeat until all elements are iterated.

You can do what you want with sum and map by first calculating all distances from one point to the next and then summing them:

```
path = [(1,2),(3,4),(1,8)]
sum(map(lambda x,y: math.sqrt((x[0]-y[0])**2+(x[1]-y[1])**2), path[:-1],path[1:]))
```

edit: or with the `hypot` function (thx @ralu):

```
sum(map(lambda x,y: math.hypot(x[0]-y[0],x[1]-y[1]), path[:-1],path[1:]))
```

Comment: Despite the naming convention and the incorrect code in the question, your `x` is actually the coordinates of the first point, and your `y` is the coordinates of the next point. So this won't return the correct distance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `redux` meta-iterator that can be combined with the built-in `reduce` to get the result you want.  This implementation avoids all buffering of the input sequence.

```
def redux(f):
  def execute(iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    try:
      state = iterable.next()
    except StopIteration:
      raise ValueError, 'empty sequences not supported'
    while True:
      newstate = iterable.next()
      yield f(state, newstate)
      state = newstate
  return execute

f = redux(lambda x, y: math.sqrt((y[0] - x[0])**2 + (y[1] - x[1])**2))
print reduce(operator.add, f(((1,2),(3,4),(1,8))))
```

The above prints `7.30056307975`.

The `redux` function can be generalized to support more than two arguments at a time in a sliding window, by using `inspect.getargspec` to count the number of arguments required by its function argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is just not the sort of code you want to write.
Reduce won't be a good solution.

I suggest a iterative one.
It will be the most readable, pythonic and maintainable solution.

```
import math
path = [(1,2),(3,4),(1,8)]

def calc_dist(waypoints):
    dist = 0.0
    for i in range(len(waypoints) - 1):
        a = waypoints[i]
        b = waypoints[i+1]
        dist += math.hypot(a[0]-b[0], b[1]-a[1])
    return dist

print calc_dist( path )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that what I'm about to suggest is not ideal, but I think this is as close as I can get for my contribution. This is a fun problem to solve, even if it isn't the most traditional application of reduce.

The key issue seems to be keeping track of the distance from point to point without overwriting the points themselves- adding another 'dimension' to each point gives you a field with which you can track the running distance.

```
iterable = ((1,2,0), (3,4,0), (1,8,0))
# originally ((1,2), (3,4), (1,8))

from math import sqrt

def func(tup1, tup2):
    '''function to pass to reduce'''

    # extract coordinates
    x0 = tup1[0]
    x1 = tup2[0]
    y0 = tup1[1]
    y1 = tup2[1]

    dist = tup1[2] # retrieve running total for distance

    dx = x1 - x0   # find change in x
    dy = y1 - y0   # find change in y

    # add new distance to running total
    dist += sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2) 

    # return 2nd point with the updated distance
    return tup2[:-1] + (dist,)  # e.g. (3, 4, 2.828)
```

Now reduce:

```
reduce(func, iterable)[-1]
# returns 7.3005630797457695
```

This way, the intermediate tuple of tuples (i.e., after one 'reduction') becomes:

```
((3, 4, 2.8284271247461903), (1,8,0))
```

Comment: This essentially implements a two-step reduce, using the third element in each tuple as the result of the first step.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is an alternate solution with a slightly different approach than the `reduce(sum, map(hypot, zip(...)))` approach.

```
tot = ((1,2),(3,4),(1,8))
reduce(lambda (d,(x,y)),b: (d+math.hypot(x-b[0],y-b[1]), b), tot, (0, tot[0]))[0]
```

Note that the `reduce` actually returns the tuple (distance, last point), hence the `[0]` at the end.  I *think* this would be more efficient than `zip` solutions but haven't actually checked.